# How to get the value within a script that has no class name?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape information from a website using Selenium.

A snippet of the html code is below:

```
<script>
  window.RI.storeId = "1";    
</script>
```

How can I get the "1" value despite there not being a class name?

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: view-source:https://us.riverisland.com/how-can-we-help/find-a-store/oxford-street-301

The snippet of code in the OP is only in the source code

Answer (score 0):

Use the `find_elements_by_tag_name()` then iterate and check the `element.get_attribute("textContent")` contains `window.RI.storeId` and then do some string manipulation.you can use some regex as well.

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("script")

for element in elements:
    if "window.RI.storeId" in element.get_attribute("textContent"):
        scripttext=element.get_attribute("textContent")
        break

print(scripttext.split('"')[1])
```

---

If you want to use regex you need to import re.

```
import re

elements=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("script")

for element in elements:
    if "window.RI.storeId" in element.get_attribute("textContent"):
        scripttext=element.get_attribute("textContent")
        break
print(re.findall("[window.RI.storeId\s=\s\"]\d{1}",scripttext)[0].split('"')[-1])
```